# Zkemkeeper.dll working from visual studio but not working on IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, zkemkeeper

I'm using zkemkeeper in asp.net mvc project work fine in development but when I publish website on IIS on my device (same computer where development work) zkemkeeper not working and I have error as on bellow

```
Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {00853A19- 
BD51-419B-9269-2DABE57EB61F} failed due to the following error: 80040154 
Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 
(REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0L1Ou.jpg)

Comment: Not sure what exactly the issue is, but, check if the DLL files are placed at the right location.  during the development, you might have placed them in a location that may not be the same while you do the deployment.

Answer (score 0):

Go to IIS > App Pools
Then Select Required App Pool And Goo To Advance Settings And You Find Enable 32bit Applications And Set It to true..

[image]